# Nhibernate mapping generator that supports mapping by code from 3.2

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am looking for an NHiberate mapping generator that can generate mapping by code rather than .xml or Fluent NHibernate.

I tried [NHibernate Mapping Generator](https://nmg.codeplex.com/), but it has no validation. Thus, the existing mapping files might not 100% correct.

[Devart Entity developer](http://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper/) doesn't support this currently.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [nHibernate Designer](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/nhdesigner) from MindScape.

Answer (score 0):

Well since you are asking for a suggestion, I can say by experience don't try to use a code generator. Such kind of approach fails when the project grow, you suddenly need to add some modifications and re-generating the entities would be a pain and so on. Try to read about [ConventionalMapping](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.it/2011/07/nhibernate-playing-with-mapping-by-code_17.html). It is basically a strategy in building the mapping on the fly based on some conventions generally exists in a database table vs classes naming. I did this in past and with a little effort you will be able to concentrate just on the classes and completely forgot the mapping.